# How do I interpret chromium's "Record Heap Allocations" graphs?

Tags: javascript, debugging, memory-leaks, chromium

If I see:

[image]

Should I interpret this to mean the blue lines are currently allocated memory, and the gray lines are allocated and released?  I'm trying to understand how to read this so I can understand if I'm writing leaky Javascript code.  I'm coming from a C/C++ background and am trying to understand how Javascript's garbage collection is supposed to treat my code.

For reference, here is what I have loaded:

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autoreload.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

autoreload.js:

```
function checkAndReload()
{
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', window.location.href);
  http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (http.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      return;
    }
    if (http.status !== 200) {
      return;
    }

    // compare current last modified with last modified from server
    var this_last_modified = Date.parse(document.lastModified);
    var checked_last_modified = Date.parse(http.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
    var diff = checked_last_modified - this_last_modified;

    if(diff > 0) location.reload(true);
  };
  http.send();
}


// run checkAndReload() once per second
window.setInterval(checkAndReload, 1000);
```

I'm trying to implement a script that will autoreload the page given the `<script ...></script>` line is there.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: FWIW I tried using the profiler on this page [link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/demos/memory/example8) and still could not understand what I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's pretty well explained here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKwmdTByxLk

The gray bars mean that the memory will be collected by the garbage collector at some point in the future, and the blue bars mean the memory is actively being referenced and will not be garbage collected.